# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PEAR_Exception' not found

Tags: php, macos, pear

I am encountering an unusual error on Mac OSx

```
[Sun Dec 15 18:13:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PEAR_Exception' not found in /path/file.php on line 102
```

I am sure that i have the extension 'Pear' installed. (Simply running "pear" on the terminal does not show a "command not found" error)

What could have caused this error ?

Comment: Is PEAR in your PHP `include_path`?

Comment: Sorry, i am new to php, how do i check that ?

Comment: Do `<?php phpinfo();` and look for `include_path`.

Comment: Yes it is under `include_path`.

Comment: Have you included the class `PEAR_Exception` in the file that is calling it? Like so `require_once 'PEAR/Exception.php';`?

Answer (score 0):

To use PEAR and PEAR compatible packages in your applications, you normally include them into your PHP scripts using `require_once()`. For this to work, PEAR's directory must be a part of PHP's `include_path`.

You can check PHP's `include path` with `<?php phpinfo();` and look for `include_path`. On Mac OS X, PEAR is installed in `/usr/lib/php/PEAR` by default.

Once you have verified that PEAR is installed and included in PHP's `include_path`, you can include the needed PEAR package using `require_once()`. **You must do this before using any function associated with that package or you will get an error.**

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PEAR_Exception' not found in /path/file.php
>   on line 102

For example you need to do `require_once 'PEAR/Exception.php';` before you can use the package PEAR_Exception.